# Firebase / AngularFire - How Do I Mock a Firebase Reference That I Chained $loaded() To?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, jasmine, angularfire

I connect to my Firebase object using the following function:

```
$scope.getData= function(param){
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseConstants.url + 'data/' + param);
    var sync = $firebase(ref.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(1));
    return sync.$asArray();
};
```

I use the above method in the following fashion:

```
$scope.setData= function(param){
    var lastMessage = $scope.getData(param);
    lastMessage.$loaded().then(function(){
        $scope.message = lastMessage.message;
        $scope.images = lastMessage.images;
    }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

In my Jasmine test file, I have the following:

```
describe('setData Test', function(){
    it('should please me', function(){
        var param = 932489234;
        spyOn(scope, 'getData').and.returnValue({
            $loaded: function(){
                deferred = q.defer();
                deferred.resolve({
                    $id: 'talk to you',
                    message: 'brother',
                    images: {
                        0: 'www.google.com',
                        1: 'www.paper.com',
                        2: 'www.sun.com'
                    }
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });
        scope.setData(param);
        scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

The above test allows me to simulate `$loaded()` being resolved, but I am not able to get the value of `lastMessage` after the promise has resolved.

It seems `lastMessage` first returns a function in the form of a promise and then the return value changes to the actual response object after the initial promise resolves.

How do I simulate this in my Jasmine test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this by using the callback function parameter chained to `$loaded()`.  Instead of using:

```
lastMessage.$loaded().then(function(){}
```

I used

```
lastMessage.$loaded().then(function(data){
    // lastMessage === data
})
```

`data` in this case will have the same value as `lastMessage` in the callback function.  This will allow you to assign a value to `data` in your Jasmine test by using the following:

```
deferred.resolve({
    $id: 'talk to you',
    message: 'brother',
    images: {
        0: 'www.google.com',
        1: 'www.paper.com',
        2: 'www.sun.com'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the number of times the $loaded function has been called. If it's the first call, return the promise, if it's the second call, return the resolved value.

Something like this:

```
_calls: 0,
$loaded: function() {
  var self = this;
  self._calls += 1;
  if (self._calls === 1) {
    // ...
    return deferred.promise.then(function(value) {
      self._resolvedValue = value;
      return value;
    });
  } else {
    return self._resolvedValue;
  }
}
```